# Add column in my sql with values from 1 to 7

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database with 819 rows. The database has an id as a primary key for each row.
what i would like to do is contsruct a query that will add a new column to the database
and it will contain numbers from 1 to 7.
example:

[image: a mockup of what im trying to achieve]

How can I make a query to add the new_column (see picture) to have this values, without having to type them one by one. Is that possible?
thank you

Comment: Do you want these to go in some sort of sequence, or at random?

Comment: This (another) one of those situations where MySQL's lack of window functions really hurts. If it supported them, this additional column could easily be added when running a query without the need for an update or adding a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `id` column isn't consecutive (i.e has gaps or isn't ordered) - you can do it with variables:

```
--add column:
ALTER TABLE t ADD newNum INT(11);
--fill column:
UPDATE 
  t 
  CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT @num:=0) AS init
SET 
  newNum=IF(@mod:=(@num:=@num+1)%7, @mod, 7)
```

Comment: This worked Except for the first and the 16nth row , but i can do the corrections manually. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

Try to use modulo operation

```
SET @rowid = 0;

UPDATE table SET new_column = MOD((@rowid:=@rowid + 1) - 1 ,7) + 1
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name or it may be just not ordered well, yes

Comment: Both are right. I've made some updates. Thanks for the feedback.